# create a queue with multiple data types

Tags: c++, queue, c++17

I want to be able to have a queue class that can accept "any" preferred data type wether that is a CURL type or just a std::string type. Queue of strings or queue of curl handles if you will.

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>

#include "queue_safe.h"

void SafeQueue::initialize() {

    /* initialize a std::queue */

    safe_queue = {};
    
}

std::string SafeQueue::get() {

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> condition_lock(queue_lock);

    if (safe_queue.empty()) {

        if (ready.wait_for(condition_lock, std::chrono::seconds(20)) == std::cv_status::timeout) {

            /* timeout was reached, no items left */

            return std::string();
        }

        /* if a timeout was not hit, but the queue was empty previously this will execute */

        std::string element = safe_queue.front();

        safe_queue.pop();

        return element;

        
    }

    else {

        /* not empty, return an element */

        std::string element = safe_queue.front();

        safe_queue.pop();

        return element;
    }

    /* do not need a return value here since empty HAS to be either true/false */

}

void SafeQueue::put(std::string& element) {

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> put_guard(queue_lock);

    safe_queue.push(element);

    ready.notify_one();

}

uint8_t SafeQueue::empty() {

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> empty_guard(queue_lock);
    
    if (safe_queue.size() == 0) {

        return 1;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

queue.cpp

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <condition_variable>

class SafeQueue {
public:
    std::condition_variable ready;
    std::mutex queue_lock;

    std::queue<std::string> safe_queue;
    uint8_t empty();
    void initialize();
    void put(std::string& element);
    std::string get();
};
```

queue.h
This works fine for a single type (string). But how could i adapt it to allow any wanted type like mentioned above?

Comment: You can use `std::variant` as the type of the queue.

Comment: This question is "fix my solution". I'd like to ask: "what is your actual problem?". What is the functionality you like to achieve. This kind of ques usually are holding a function, for example `std::function<void()>` to switch processing of some data to different thread.

Comment: IMO you should first explain how you intend to use this `SafeQueue` to avoid current [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) you question suffers from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a single object corresponding to a single type. You must use Template Classes:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class SafeQueue {
public:
    std::condition_variable ready;
    std::mutex queue_lock;

    std::queue<T> safe_queue;
    uint8_t empty();
    void initialize();
    void put(T& element);
    T get();
};
```

But if you need a queue with multi-ply types, you could use `std::any`:

```
class SafeQueue {
public:
    std::condition_variable ready;
    std::mutex queue_lock;

    std::queue<std::any> safe_queue;
    uint8_t empty();
    void initialize();
    void put(std::any& element);
    std::any get();
};
```

---

But it's better to have a structure for that to store the underlying type for better communication with your class API's.

Comment: template classes is what i need.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the types you want to store in the queue up front, you can use [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant). Being a type-safe union, `std::variant` guarantees that it contains one of a list of types; it also has better performance than `std::any` since a variant exists in automatic storage.

For example, this variant type can store one of `std::string`, `int` or `double`:

```
using MyVariant = std::variant<std::string, int, double>;
```

You can use a queue of `MyVariant` in your class `SafeQueue`. Finally, use a visitor to process each item in your queue.

I've reworked you class here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

using MyVariant = std::variant<std::string, int, double>;

template<class> inline constexpr bool always_false_v = false;

class SafeQueue {
public:
    std::condition_variable ready;
    std::mutex queue_lock;

    std::queue<MyVariant> safe_queue;
    uint8_t empty();
    void initialize();
    void put(MyVariant element);
    MyVariant get();
};

void SafeQueue::initialize() {

    /* initialize a std::queue */

    safe_queue = {};

}

MyVariant SafeQueue::get() {

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> condition_lock(queue_lock);

    if (safe_queue.empty()) {

        if (ready.wait_for(condition_lock, std::chrono::seconds(20)) == std::cv_status::timeout) {

            /* timeout was reached, no items left */

            return std::string();
        }

        /* if a timeout was not hit, but the queue was empty previously this will execute */

        auto element = safe_queue.front();

        safe_queue.pop();

        return element;
    }

    else {

        /* not empty, return an element */

        auto element = safe_queue.front();

        safe_queue.pop();

        return element;
    }

    /* do not need a return value here since empty HAS to be either true/false */

}

void SafeQueue::put(MyVariant element) {

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> put_guard(queue_lock);

        safe_queue.push(std::move(element));
    }

    ready.notify_one();

}

uint8_t SafeQueue::empty() {

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> empty_guard(queue_lock);

    if (safe_queue.empty()) {

        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
   SafeQueue q;
    q.put("hello");
    q.put(1);
    q.put(2.3);

    //Use visitor pattern to print elements from queue
    while (!q.empty()) {
        auto elem = q.get();
        std::visit([](auto&& arg) {
            using T = std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>;
            if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
                std::cout << "std::string with value " << std::quoted(arg) << '\n';
            else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
                std::cout << "int with value " << arg << '\n';
            else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>)
                std::cout << "double with value " << arg << '\n';
            else
                static_assert(always_false_v<T>, "non-exhaustive visitor!");
            }, elem);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
std::string with value "hello"
int with value 1
double with value 2.3
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ws9oM1Ma1)

Comment: this is not what i am looking for, i do not need multiple types in ONE queue/vector

Comment: @noah Yes. A vector of variants can hold multiple types in one queue/vector. So in the example above, the queue can hold `int`s, `std::string`s and `double`s, not just one type.

Comment: i only need one type in one vector not mixed so i just need an overloaded function i suppose

Comment: @noah The question title is misleading then. It states a queue of multiple data types. If you just want one data type, then you could use a template class or simply `std::vector`. I thought since you tagged this under C++17 you wanted to store multiple data types in one queue.